# PHP multi array get value

Tags: php, arrays, variables

How can i get the value of a multi array.
So i need out of my array the [user_login] and i the [ID]
So something like echo $array[user_login] where [ID] is $variable[ID]

I need a solution which works without using echo $array[0][user_login]

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 15
            [user_login] => Loginname
            [user_nicename] => Loginname
            [user_email] => mail@mail.com
            [user_url] => http://www.domain.com
            [user_registered] => 2014-10-26 09:39:01
            [user_activation_key] => 
            [user_status] => 0
            [display_name] => Test Inc
            [logo] => 
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 28
            [user_login] => Loginname
            [user_nicename] => Loginname
            [user_email] => mail@mail.com
            [user_url] => http://www.domain.com
            [user_registered] => 2014-10-26 09:39:01
            [user_activation_key] => 
            [user_status] => 0
            [display_name] => Test Inc
            [logo] => 
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 13
            [user_login] => Loginname
            [user_nicename] => Loginname
            [user_email] => mail@mail.com
            [user_url] => http://www.domain.com
            [user_registered] => 2014-10-26 09:39:01
            [user_activation_key] => 
            [user_status] => 0
            [display_name] => Test Inc
            [logo] => 
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 11
            [user_login] => Loginname
            [user_nicename] => Loginname
            [user_email] => mail@mail.com
            [user_url] => http://www.domain.com
            [user_registered] => 2014-10-26 09:39:01
            [user_activation_key] => 
            [user_status] => 0
            [display_name] => Test Inc
            [logo] => 
        )
)
```

Comment: So you have a variable, like `$id`, and you need the `user_login` that corresponds that id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could loop through that array to create a new one:

```
$newArray = array();
foreach($array as $item){
    $newArray[$item->ID] = $item;
}
```

Then with that you can access things using `$newArray[$id]->whateveritem;`

Comment: Have you tried your code? That's an array of objects, not a multidimensional array

Comment: It Wasn't Me. I will test. @Tivie have you a better solution?

Comment: @Matthias I was talking to JammyDodger231

Comment: Ahh I see now, I have edited it to take the object from the array and split the ID thanks @Tivie

Answer (score 2):

That's an array of objects, which is a bit different than an array of arrays (or multidimensional array).

You can loop through the array until you find the correct `ID` and then grab the `user_login`. SOmething like this

```
$myID = 15; //Id to search for

foreach ($array as $obj) {
    if($obj->ID === $myID) {
        echo $obj->user_login; //Or do something with it
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Items in an array of objects are referenced like `$object->member`. An easy way to search through this array would be a simple foreach() loop. For example, to find the user with id 28, you would do:

```
foreach($array as $item) {
    if ($item->ID == '28') {
        echo 'Login is: ' . $item->user_login;
        break;
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Oops, Trivie beat me to it